# Dynamically Resizing Flotr2 Charts

Tags: javascript, html, charts, resize, flotr

Is there a good way to resize Flotr2 charts after it's rendered? The only way I know right now is to redraw it. If found that if I just change the size of the canvas, the chart simply disappears.

Comment: Inorder to do that, you need to redraw the the graph after revising the canvas.

Comment: That's what I have been doing, but it's very inconvenient and also very expensive with amount of data even if it's cached in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this plugin:

jquery.flot.resize.js

[Flotr Resize Example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/resize/)

Comment: The page you linked doesn't actually have any helpful information. Perhaps you can link to an example implementation?

Comment: Sorry, I was using also Flotr2, but after some search I got rid of it because of its limitations and got http://www.highcharts.com